# How to have a textarea to keep scrolled to the bottom when updated

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, textarea

My problem is a bit off the cuff here, so I'll try to explain this best I can.

I have a text area, having css of `#object{overflow:hidden;resize:none;}`. I am trying to prevent it from spawning scroll bar while also resizing itself. This textarea is synced with an external script's console meaning it updates. By default however, it will stay at the top unless you highlight text, dragging off to the bottom of the element. This would be the only way to scroll down other than with arrow keys, naturally.

Programmatically, is there any way to keep the text area down to the bottom upon updating?  It would be nice to have it auto-scroll to accommodate its use case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set textarea scroll bar to bottom as a default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170670/how-do-i-set-textarea-scroll-bar-to-bottom-as-a-default)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can do it by javascript. Set the `scrollTop` property of text area with `scrollHeight` property like below:

```
document.getElementById("textarea").scrollTop = document.getElementById("textarea").scrollHeight
```

Comment: Love it! Thanks. Nothing worked except for this solution. Saved me time. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 22):

By using jQuery, you can find out when the content of the `textarea` changes using:

```
$("#object").change(function() {
  scrollToBottom();
});
```

And scroll to the bottom using:

```
function scrollToBottom() {
  $('#object').scrollTop($('#object')[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

Scroll code taken from [jquerybyexample.blogspot.com](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-scroll-to-bottom-of-textarea.html).

Comment: Thanks but I write all my "low level code" and don't use any libraries other then my own.

Comment: Disagree, I love the jQuery solution :D

Comment: @ecbrodie good for you but it's not good for everyone by any means, terrible syntax conventions that don't match up with most other code bases now a days

Comment: @Alex you also realize that I posted this comment EIGHT YEARS AGO, right? The JavaScript ecosystem has changed vastly since then. I also haven't used jQuery in at least 4 years, given there are many alternatives to it now. I don't think it's reasonable to hold me to a stance I had so long ago.

Answer (score 7):

**Using Javascript**

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea_id');
textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
```

**Using Jquery**

```
$('#textarea_id').scrollTop($('#textarea_id')[0].scrollHeight);​​​
```

Comment: Party ended a while ago but have an upvote. Hope you don't mind it's a bit crunchy. ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Generic JQuery Plugin**

Here a generic jquery plugin for scrollBottom of any element:

```
$.fn.scrollBottom = function() {
  return $(this).scrollTop($(this)[0].scrollHeight);
};
```

usage:

```
$("#logfile").val( $("#logfile").val() + "this is new line test\n" ).scrollBottom();
```

Comment: Concise, worked as advertised.

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkTextareaHeight(){
   var textarea = document.getElementById("yourTextArea");
   if(textarea.selectionStart == textarea.selectionEnd) {
      textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
   }
}
```

Call this function every time when the contents of the textarea are changed. If you cannot edit the external influence, periodically activate this function using setInterval.