# Angular JS showing last few lines in textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have a textarea and by default it shows the contents from the beginning. I want to make it show the end contents by default and if you scroll up it should show the contents at the top.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

Manipulating the DOM from your controller is generally considered bad practice. 
I would think the best way to go about this is creating a directive that watches your text area's value and let it handle the DOM manipulation.

```
angular.module('directivesModule').directive('showTail', function () {
    return function (scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.$watch(function () {
            return elem[0].value;
        },
        function (e) {
            elem[0].scrollTop = elem[0].scrollHeight;
        });
    }

});
```

Then it's just a matter of adding the directive to your text area

```
<textarea show-tail></textarea>
```

Comment: I got an Error: `$injector:nomod Module Unavailable`. When I changed `module('directivesModule')` to `module('directivesModule',[])` the error was not in my console but the scroll is still not working. Probably this example is for an older version of angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can install [angular-scroll-glue](https://github.com/Luegg/angularjs-scroll-glue) with npm or bower.

Then in your module dependencies add 'luegg.directives' (see link).

And add the directive to your textarea:

```
<textarea scroll-glue></textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

See question [How do I set textarea scroll bar to bottom as a default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170670/how-do-i-set-textarea-scroll-bar-to-bottom-as-a-default)

Basically this is not angularjs specific, you just have to add in your controller:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea_id');
textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: As @Mike De Swert mentioned, any sort of DOM manipulation should be handled within a directive. That's how Angular does it (`ng-repeat`, `ng-cloak`, etc), and that's how generally we are encouraged to do it.