# Keeping text entered into a textarea visible at all times

Tags: javascript

When entering text into a textarea manually, it remains visible at all times. However I'm using a simple javascript function to enter some text when an icon on the page is clicked.

```
onClick="addline('xyz')

function addline(sometext) 
if(sometext == "xyz")
{
  document.getElementById('thearea').value = "Hello world!\n";
}
```

The problem is, when text entered this way reaches the bottom of the textarea, it disappears from view and the scrollbar just lengthens.

My question is, is there any way to keep the text visible at all times?  Thanks.

Thank you for referring me to a similar request for assistance. I have done what I thought was a comprehensive search here and on other web sites to a solution to this issue before posting. Unfortunately, the code suggested doesn't make any difference, the text added using the above function remains hidden in my textarea until the scrollbar down arrow is clicked.

Comment: could you make a fiddle or code snippet please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set textarea scroll bar to bottom as a default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170670/how-do-i-set-textarea-scroll-bar-to-bottom-as-a-default)