# How to show the end of text in a textarea

Tags: html

I have an HTML page that contains a textarea with a long text.

Currently, when I open the page, I see the beginning of the text in the textarea, and have to go down inside the textarea in order to see the end of text.

Is there a way to instruct the browser to automatically show the end of the text in the textarea (so that the user will have to go up inside the textarea to see its beginning)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set textarea scroll bar to bottom as a default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170670/how-do-i-set-textarea-scroll-bar-to-bottom-as-a-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it with html alone, but use javascript to scroll to bottom of the text area as mentioned here - [How do I set textarea scroll bar to bottom as a default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170670/how-do-i-set-textarea-scroll-bar-to-bottom-as-a-default)

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea_id');
textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Demo**

```js
var elmnt = document.getElementById("target");
elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

```css
.content{
  border:1px solid black;
  height:1000px;
}
.a{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="a">textArea:<input type="textarea" id="target"></div>
</div>
```