# Dynamically scroll textarea to bottome

Tags: javascript, textarea, scrolltop

I'm just starting to learn javascript and ajax. I have a textarea, which upon pressing the enter button, it sends a request to the server and what comes back is supposed to be shown in the same textarea. Although I ve managed to do the connection with the server, I cant make the textarea to scroll down after the response. This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<body>
<textarea id="myDiv"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var terminal = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    console.log(terminal);
    getBrowserDimensions();

    document.getElementById("myDiv").onkeydown = function(event){
        var e = event || window.event;
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            loadXMLDoc(terminal.value);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my javascript file:

```
function loadXMLDoc(sendString){
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHHTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            terminal.value += xmlhttp.responseText+'\n';
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "php/demo_get.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(sendString);
    terminal.scrollTop = terminal.scrollHeight;
    console.log("1: " + terminal.scrollTop);
    console.log("2: " + terminal.scrollHeight);
}

function getBrowserDimensions(){
    var x = window.innerWidth;
    var y = window.innerHeight;
    var terminalWidth = Math.floor(x * 0.95);
    var terminalHeight = Math.floor(y * 0.95);
    terminal.value += "width: " + x + " height: " + y + " tWidth : " + terminalWidth + '\n';
    terminal.style.width = terminalWidth + "px";
    terminal.style.height = terminalHeight + "px";
    terminal.style.resize = "none";
}
```

I've tried some approaches found mostly in this site like:

```
terminal.scrollTop = terminal.scrollHeight - terminal.clientHeight;
```

But nothing changed. The textarea would keep being set to the middle of its scrollable height. Even setting the scrollTop to a fixed number like 9999 would not make anything different. I've tried this in firefox and in chrome. I am also not supposed to use jquery, so if any ideas on what I am doing wrong, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should just be `scrollTop = scrollHeight`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have a textarea to keep scrolled to the bottom when updated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373081/how-to-have-a-textarea-to-keep-scrolled-to-the-bottom-when-updated)

Comment: what do you mean "It should just be scrollTop = scrollHeight"? arent these methods of an object? i ve seen the possible duplicate and still won't provide any solution that works.

Comment: They're properties, not methods (no parenthesis), and it *should* just be `terminal.scrollTop = terminal.scrollHeight;`.  If that's not working then there's something else causing the problem.

Comment: this is all the javascript code that is loaded :(

Comment: I should have spotted the problem earlier.  The answer below should help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ajax call is asynchronous, which means you're making the call, creating an event handler for when it's completed and then setting the scrollTop value before that actually happens.  Try this instead...

```
function loadXMLDoc(sendString){
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHHTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            terminal.value += xmlhttp.responseText+'\n';
            terminal.scrollTop = terminal.scrollHeight;
            console.log("1: " + terminal.scrollTop);
            console.log("2: " + terminal.scrollHeight);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "php/demo_get.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(sendString);
}
```

Comment: ok! that wouldn't even cross my mind. more study study study for me. thank you very much, worked perfectly. :)