# Textarea auto-scroll to the bottom

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea that I append data to with `textarea.value += "more text\n";` and I would like it to "stay" scrolled to the bottom, so it would always show the last line.

I have read that I should do:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea_id');
textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
```

But I tried that (http://jsfiddle.net/BenjiWiebe/mya0u1zo/) and I can't get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a textarea to keep scrolled to the bottom when updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373081/how-to-have-a-textarea-to-keep-scrolled-to-the-bottom-when-updated)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set textarea scroll bar to bottom as a default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170670/how-do-i-set-textarea-scroll-bar-to-bottom-as-a-default)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to set `scrollTop` each time you append text:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea_id');
setInterval(function(){
    textarea.value += Math.random()+'\n';
    textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mya0u1zo/2/

Comment: OK, So there is no way of making it "stick" to the bottom? Because I have multiple places in my code that append text... though I guess I could create a function `append_text`...

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question: since your string output ends with a newline, you should scroll before you output, not after (I keep my ids in an object called id):

```
function Output(Msg)
  {
  ...
  id.Log.scrollTop=id.Log.scrollHeight;
  SetValue('Log',out);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip! It makes more sense to scroll first, and add content later. What I've also found out is that, in this case, there is a tendency for the scrolling to stop half-way on the _last_ line only (but it nevertheless scrolls line by line!). A bit of padding at the bottom is usually enough to get rid of that unwanted effect (I'm just using `1.5rem`, but possibly one could get away with other values). This is also quite fast — much faster than I expected, to the point that now I'm considering _animating_ the whole scrolling (to make it slower that way!).