# Keep scroll in the bottom of the chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pug

I'm currently working on a chat on a webpage for a project, but I have encountered a problem with the chat. When I write a new message, the message appears under the (hidden) chatbox and I have to manually scroll to see the messages. I'm working with Jade, CSS and JS but have not found a solution.

I have a div called #chatwrapper and inside that I have .content

**this is the Jade**

```
        .formwrapper
           form(id='messageform', action='', method='GET')
           textarea(class='form-control1' type='text' id='messagefield'autocomplete='off') 
           input(class='pure-button' type='submit' id='sendmessage' value='send')
```

**this is the CSS**

```
#chatwrapper {
  float: left;
  background-color: none;
  height:100%;
  width:380px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

**CSS for the content**

```
    #chatwrapper .content, #feedwrapper .content{
  height: 440px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #EDEDED;
  margin: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #888888;
```

Comment: add a fiddle or codepen or a link  or something. The actual html would help a bit

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373081/how-to-have-a-textarea-to-keep-scrolled-to-the-bottom-when-updated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll to bottom of div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)