# textarea auto scroll to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, button, textarea

I'm trying to get my textarea to scroll to the bottom if new text is inserted. But I just can't get it to work.

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="txt-area" readonly rows="21" cols="48"></textarea>
<button class="buttons" value="1">1</button>
<button class="buttons" value="2">2</button>
<button class="buttons" value="3">3</button>
<button class="buttons" value="4">4</button>
<input type="button" class="buttons" value="Test">
<input type="button" class="Backspace" value="DEL">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var values = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".buttons").click(function () {
        var cntrl = $(this).html();
        if ($(this)[0].nodeName == "INPUT" )
        {
                cntrl = $(this).attr( "value" );
        }

        $("#txt-area").val(function (_, val){
            return val + cntrl
        });
        values.push($(this).val());
        $("#txt-area").val(values.join("\n"));
    });
            $('.Backspace').on('click', function () {
            values.pop();
            $('#txt-area').val(values.join("\n"));
        });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttons").click(function(){
        $('#txt-area').scrollTop($('#txt-area').scrollHeight);    
    });

});
```

My code is also in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPYCV/47/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381817/how-do-i-determine-scrollheight]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a textarea to keep scrolled to the bottom when updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373081/how-to-have-a-textarea-to-keep-scrolled-to-the-bottom-when-updated)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set textarea scroll bar to bottom as a default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170670/how-do-i-set-textarea-scroll-bar-to-bottom-as-a-default)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change

```
$('#txt-area').scrollTop($('#txt-area').scrollHeight);
```

to

```
$('#txt-area').scrollTop($('#txt-area')[0].scrollHeight);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/cPYCV/48/

Comment: indeed, making a log of `$('#txt-area').scrollHeight` outputs `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your JavaScript

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('txt-area');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 1000);
```